# Colab No module named 'tensorflow.examples.tutorials'

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm a beginner in this field
**Using Colab**, I have a problem
there aren't `tensorflow.examples.tutorials`
I have checked something is existed or not
there is only one thing called `examples.saved_model`

if you know how to download or connect with Colab

Please give me a solution

```
ModuleNotFoundError:Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-da20ef9adb09> in <module>()
----> 1 from tensorflow.examples.tutorials import mnist

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.examples.tutorials'
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.examples.tutorials'
```

**tensorflow.examples.tutorials** is now deprecated, hence you received this error.

It is recommended to use **tensorflow.keras.datasets**, please refer below code

```
import tensorflow as tf
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

For more details please refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering.

I want to use examples's minist functions but there is no way to use that..